# Convert hex to binary and send it over network

Tags: bash, hex, pipe, netcat, xxd

I need to read hexadecimal data from stdin, convert it to binary, send with `netcat`, recieve reply, convert back to hex and print to stdout. I do:

```
# xxd -r -p | nc -u localhost 12345 | xxd
```

Then type my data in hex and press Enter. But it is not sent untill I press `Ctrl+D`, so I'm unable to sent another packet after receiving reply. Looks like `xxd -r -p` doesn't write binary data, until `EOF` is given. Is there a way to make it write after newline?

Comment: Why do you need to send it as binary? hex should work just fine. Binary is actualy taking the number of bytes needed and multiplying it by 4 (hex is 2 digs per byte, binary is 8 per byte, 2/8=4)

Comment: @phyrrus9 I think the OPs definition here of "binary" is a stream of 8-bit bytes, and not a stream of ascii 1s and 0s.  For example, try `echo 737461636b6f766572666c6f772e636f6d0a | xxd -p -r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, most *nix utilities will do line buffering when in interactive mode (e.g. stdin/stdout connected directly to the terminal emulator).  But when in non-interactive mode (e.g. stdin/stdout connected to a pipe) larger buffers are typically used - I think 8k or so is typical, but this varies largely by implementation/distro.

You can force buffering for a given process to line mode using the [GNU `stdbuf` utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html), if you have it available:

```
stdbuf -oL xxd -r -p | nc -u localhost 12345 | xxd
```